# Valid query returns NULL using PDO & MySQLi

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a really weird problem which I assume must be a bug in a library somewhere but for the life of me I can't figure out where it is in order to lodge a bug report in the appropriate place

I am writing some code that accesses the mysql database that is created by the kodi application

I am trying to search that database for a filename.

Some filenames contain strange characters.

Consider this code (PDO based, I have also written it using MYSQLi with the same result)

```
$filename = $conn->quote('Aliens.1986.[1080p|1.85|H.264]-YIFY.mp4');
$sql = "SELECT m.idMovie FROM movie m LEFT JOIN files f ON m.idFile = f.idFile WHERE f.strFilename=".$filename;
$statement = $conn->query($sql);
var_dump($statement);
var_dump($statement->fetch());

$filename=$conn->quote('Alien.3.1992.[720p|2.39|H.264]-YIFY.mp4');
$sql = "SELECT m.idMovie FROM movie m LEFT JOIN files f ON m.idFile = f.idFile WHERE f.strFilename=".$filename;
$statement = $conn->query($sql);
var_dump($statement);
var_dump($statement->fetch());
```

This code returns;

```
object(PDOStatement)#2 (1) {
["queryString"]=>
string(132) "SELECT m.idMovie FROM movie m LEFT JOIN files f ON m.idFile = f.idFile WHERE f.strFilename='Aliens.1986.[1080p|1.85|H.264]-YIFY.mp4'"
}
array(2) {
["idMovie"]=>
string(3) "185"
[0]=>
string(3) "185"
}
object(PDOStatement)#3 (1) {
["queryString"]=>
string(132) "SELECT m.idMovie FROM movie m LEFT JOIN files f ON m.idFile = f.idFile WHERE f.strFilename='Alien³.1992.[720p|2.39|H.264]-YIFY.mp4'"}
bool(false)
```

As you can see the second query returns false. However, if I take the sql from that query & paste it directly into mysql it returns the correct value;

```
mysql> SELECT m.idMovie FROM movie m LEFT JOIN files f ON m.idFile = f.idFile WHERE f.strFilename='Alien³.1992.[720p|2.39|H.264]-YIFY.mp4';
+---------+
| idMovie |
+---------+
|    5151 |
+---------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)
```

I have also tried to escape the superscript 3 like so; Alien\³.1992, which exhibits exactly the same behavior, it really has me stumped.

If I change the filename to Alien.3 it works as expected so it does have something to do with the superscript character 3

If anybody can explain what is going on here I would be very grateful

Edit:

Here is the code that was ultimately successful;

```
$filename = 'Alien³.1992.[720p|2.39|H.264]-YIFY.mp4';
$statement = $conn->prepare("SELECT m.idMovie FROM movie m LEFT JOIN files f ON m.idFile = f.idFile WHERE f.strFilename = ?");
var_dump($statement->execute(array($filename)));
var_dump($statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));
```

Thanks everyone!

Comment: It's preferable to use prepared statements instead of `$conn->quote()`.

Comment: Seems like an encoding issue.

Comment: **WARNING**: Whenever possible use **prepared statements** to avoid injecting arbitrary data in your queries and creating [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). These are quite straightforward to do in [`mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) where any user-supplied data is specified with a `?` or `:name` indicator that’s later populated using `bind_param` or `execute` depending on which one you’re using.

Comment: Check that you're using UTF-8 *all the way through*. It's a common mistake that one step in the chain is not UTF-8 and that's when things get all screwed up. Characters like ™ or ³ are not helped by using the backslash as a literal. They're not special characters, they're *multi-byte* characters in UTF-8.

Comment: Thanks for the tip on prepared statements, much appreciated. The code I posted was simple test code to demonstrate the issue, not code I am intending to use. The table is already set to utf8 by kodi devs, I will check out forcing the utf8 encoding in the php side

Comment: I rewrote the code using prepared statements & it did work. That is interesting. Thanks everyone